# Symfony 4 do not build in Production: Attempted to load class "WebProfilerBundle" from namespace

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces, production

Symfony 4 do build in Dev mode but do not in Production mode while producing the error:

Attempted to load class "WebProfilerBundle" from namespace.

The WebProfilerBundle sure, is installed but should only used in Dev environment and should not used on Production builds.

I am on Fedora30, no containerization involved.

- php -v => PHP 7.3.8 (cli) (built: Jul 30 2019 09:26:16) ( NTS )
- npm -v => 6.9.0
- yarn -v => 1.17.3
- composer.phar -V => Composer version 1.9.0 2019-08-02 20:55:32
- symfony -V => Symfony CLI version v4.6.4 (Tue Aug 13 16:14:53 CEST 2019)
- flex

Active file versioning let me guess Production build chain is used (not present Dev builds):

```
$ ls -l public/build
168 -rw-rw-r-- 1 rob rob 169693 31. Aug 15:39 0.376e4878.js
184 -rw-rw-r-- 1 rob rob 185359 31. Aug 15:39 0.6ea45216.css
  4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 rob rob    404 31. Aug 15:39 app.00b96fcb.js
  4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 rob rob    213 31. Aug 15:39 app.f7e93431.css
  4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 rob rob    261 31. Aug 15:39 entrypoints.json
  4 drwxrwxr-x 2 rob rob   4096 31. Aug 15:39 fonts
  4 drwxrwxr-x 2 rob rob   4096 31. Aug 15:39 images
  4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 rob rob   1246 31. Aug 15:39 manifest.json
  4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 rob rob   1505 31. Aug 15:39 runtime.3c075ebb.js
```

bundles.php

```
<?php

return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],

    Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],

    Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\WebpackEncoreBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

composer.json

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.4",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/console": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.4",
        "symfony/form": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/intl": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.4",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
        "symfony/process": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/translation": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/validator": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.6",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.3.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
        "symfony/test-pack": "*",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.3.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.3.*"
        }
    }
}
```

**Production builds** are build with:

- do $ `cp .env.local.prod .env.local` this contains..

  - the same as .env
  - except this line `APP_ENV=prod`
  - except the missing APP_SECRET line
- do $ `rm -rf var/cache; rm -rf vendor`
- do $ `../composer.phar install --no-dev --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-interaction`
- do $ `yarn build`
- do $ `rm .env.local` on finish the build

But this seems not work, it produces the error from above.

**Dev builds** are done with:

- do $ `rm .env.local just use .env with APP_SECRET and APP_ENV=dev`
- do $ `rm -rf var/cache; rm -rf vendor`
- do $ `../composer.phar install`
- do $ `yarn encore dev`

Error output from website

```
Attempted to load class "WebProfilerBundle" from namespace "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
(1/1) ClassNotFoundException
Attempted to load class "WebProfilerBundle" from namespace "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

in Kernel.php line 23
at Kernel->registerBundles()
in Kernel.php line 424
at Kernel->initializeBundles()
in Kernel.php line 130
at Kernel->boot()
in Kernel.php line 193
at Kernel->handle(object(Request))
in index.php line 25
```

Build process

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
Package operations: 92 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing ocramius/package-versions (1.5.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/flex (v1.4.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/annotations (v1.7.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/reflection (v1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/event-manager (v1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/collections (v1.6.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/cache (v1.8.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/persistence (1.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/common (v2.10.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/service-contracts (v1.1.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.12.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/doctrine-bridge (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle (1.3.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/stopwatch (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.12.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/console (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-eventmanager (3.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-code (3.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing ocramius/proxy-manager (2.2.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/dbal (v2.9.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/migrations (2.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.11): Loading from cache
  - Installing jdorn/sql-formatter (v1.2.17): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-common (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpdocumentor/type-resolver (0.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.12.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.12.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/mime (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v1.1.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/log (1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/debug (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/routing (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/finder (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/filesystem (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/dependency-injection (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/config (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/var-exporter (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/cache-contracts (v1.1.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/cache (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/framework-bundle (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing sensio/framework-extra-bundle (v5.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/apache-pack (v1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/dotenv (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/expression-language (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/inflector (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/property-access (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/options-resolver (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/intl (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-icu (v1.12.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/form (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-client-contracts (v1.1.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-client (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.24.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/monolog-bridge (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/monolog-bundle (v3.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/orm (v2.6.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-bundle (1.11.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle (v2.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/orm-pack (v1.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/process (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/security-core (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/security-http (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/security-guard (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/security-csrf (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/security-bundle (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/serializer (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/property-info (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing webmozart/assert (1.5.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (4.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/serializer-pack (v1.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (v3.2.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/translation-contracts (v1.1.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/translation (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing twig/twig (v2.11.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/twig-bridge (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/twig-bundle (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/validator (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/link (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing fig/link-util (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/web-link (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/asset (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/webpack-encore-bundle (v1.6.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/yaml (v4.3.3): Loading from cache
Generating optimized autoload files
ocramius/package-versions: Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
Executing script cache:clear [OK]
Executing script assets:install public [OK]

yarn run v1.17.3
$ encore production --progress
Running webpack ...

98% after emitting SizeLimitsPlugin DONE  Compiled successfully in 5450ms                                                                                                                                                            1:09:20 PM

 I  18 files written to public/build
Entrypoint app [big] = runtime.3c075ebb.js 0.6ea45216.css 0.376e4878.js app.f7e93431.css app.00b96fcb.js
Entrypoint _tmp_copy = runtime.3c075ebb.js
Done in 7.52s.
```

What i'am wondering about is and maybe its a help, in public/index.php are also debug "commands":

```
use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require dirname(__DIR__).'/config/bootstrap.php';

if ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']) {
    umask(0000);

    Debug::enable();
}

if ($trustedProxies = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? $_ENV['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedProxies(explode(',', $trustedProxies), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL ^ Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST);
}

if ($trustedHosts = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? $_ENV['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedHosts([$trustedHosts]);
}

$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Check your `config/bundles.php` to make sure it's only active for `dev` and `test` envs, not `all`.

Comment: Probably should not be removing env.local.  Sounds like that is where APP_ENV=prod is being set.  In a real production environment you would have a real environmental variable set which overrides all of the local .env files.  Does not seem like you have any set.  There is a link in the default .env file to the best practices for configurations docs.

Comment: @msg sorry, i forgot to provide bundles.php. Updated the post with that.

Comment: Config seems fine so I'm with Cerad, `APP_ENV` is defaulting to `dev` because is not set anywhere else.

Comment: I do not think so. APP_ENV=prod is setted in `.env.local` aka the Production environment. And that this thing is working correct, iam sure because the produced files in public/build are versioned in Producion builds and are not in Dev builds. 
But to get safe, i done a test with APP_ENV=prod setted in the first line of my build script. But also with no success.

Comment: @row But after the build you then *remove* `.env.local` going back to the default if the env is not set anywhere else (and that is `dev`). Even if the container is compiled in production, `bootstrap` will try to load the current env dependencies and they are just not there. Build and runtime have to be configured in the same environment.

Comment: Ok. That is a very good explanation and the reason. Thank you for enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @msg for solving this problem. My expectation was that the environment variable is only important for creating the builds and that they are somehow static. But as already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57710023/symfony-4-do-not-build-in-production-attempted-to-load-class-webprofilerbundle#comment101962289_57710023), the environment variable is also important at runtime. So because I deleted my .env.local after build, the runtime environment was immediately changed back to dev.